# ResponseCache attribute not working in some cases in vNext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using ResponseCache attribute in one very simple controller:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 60)]
public IActionResult Test()
{
   return View();
}
```

But, in my response headers, i'm getting cache-control no-cache:

[image]

I have tested the same code in other controller like this, and it's working fine...

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetMyDtoCached")]
[ResponseCache(Duration= 86400)]
public async Task<MyDto> GetMyDtoCached(string id)
{
    return await _service.getMyDtoById(id);
}
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Its getting a no-cache header from somewhere that I can see...is there anything declared in controller level? Can you post the code of TestCacheController?

Comment: No, maybe in startup.cs?

Comment: let me do some research and come back...nice qns

Comment: No more code in testcache controller...

Comment: Is the ResponseCache a extension of OutputCache attribute?

Comment: Sorry, but I used `[OutputCache(Duration = 60)]`. I got 304(not modified) for subsequent hits.

Comment: OutputCache is for ASP.NET 4.5, I'm using ASP.NET Core (VNext)

Comment: Any news about it? I am having the same issue here. Thanks.